# Can not compile boost::signal tutorial using gcc 4.5 on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: eclipse-cdt, boost-signals

I'm trying to complete the boost::signal tutorial at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html#id2850736

However Eclipse CDT shows parsing errors with whichever syntax I use

I have

```
#include <boost/signals.hpp>
```

Preferred syntax

```
boost::signal<void (float, float)> sig;    
sig.connect(&print_sum);
```

> Invalid template arguments at **signal**
>
> Method 'connect' could not be resolved

Portable syntax

```
boost::signal2<float, float, float> sig;
sig.connect(&print_sum);
```

> Method 'connect' could not be resolved
>
> Symbol 'signal2' could not be resolved

I use eclipse 3.7

Comment: Portable syntax should be signal2 - is this just a copy&paste error?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with stackoverflow editor.

Comment: Do you link with boost_signals library?

Comment: yes, I added boost_signals and boost_system to linker

Comment: These are linker issues, not compiler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to be a CDT issue. Have you updated your eclipse version lately? There is a discussion on that topic in the eclipse forum going on:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/216821/

Maybe it gives you some inspiration on how to work around that problem.

EDIT: As a temporary work around, you can disable certain code analysis features and markers. To do so, go to Window->Preferences->"C/C++"->"Code Analysis" and disable some or all problems. I have disabled all, since it will still highlight errors found during the compilation and I will not be confused by falsely declared problems.

Comment: and restart eclipse after making the changes to Code Analysis

Comment: the same problem nearly 5 years later (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643883/c-template-function-with-stdarray). Any ideas how to solve correctly and without turning off code-analysis ?