# Eclipse returns error for the code for which g++ doesn't

Tags: eclipse, g++

Building simple code (example is below) returns error on eclipse, while g++ from commandline doesn't. Both eclipse and g++ output executable that act the same (and the result meets my expectation). This is painful when the code isn't simple like the example I'm showing. Any idea is appreciated.

Env: Eclipse Indigo CDT, Ubuntu 10.10

Sample code:

```
//For test_boostStr()
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

//For test_boost_foreach()
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

void test_boostStr() {
    std::vector<std::string> strs;
    boost::split(strs, "string to split", boost::is_any_of("\t "));
    std::cout << strs.size() << std::endl;
    //  std::cout << strs.at(1) << std::endl;
}

void test_boost_foreach() {
    //std::vector<std::string> namespaces_;
    std::string namespaces_  = " tele op eration. ";
    std::cout << "managing namespaces: ";
    std::string out;
    std::string s;
    BOOST_FOREACH(s, namespaces_)
    {
        boost::trim(s);
        out += s + " ";
    }
    std::cout << out.substr(0, out.size() - 1) << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {
    test_boost_foreach();
}
```

Result of running the exec :

```
 t e l e  o p  e r a t i o n .
```

Build result in the 'Problem' tab on Eclipse:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
boost::mpl::not_<#0> * not_(#0 *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
boost::mpl::not_<#0> * not_(#0 *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
boost::mpl::not_<#0> * not_(#0 *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<boost::foreach_detail_::foreach_iterator<#0,#1>::type> end(const boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_base &, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<#0,#1> *, mpl_::bool_<0> *)
boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<int> end(const boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_base &, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<#0 *,#1> *, mpl_::bool_<1> *)
boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<boost::foreach_detail_::foreach_iterator<#0,#1>::type> end(const boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_base &, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<#0,#1> *, mpl_::bool_<1> *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<boost::foreach_detail_::foreach_iterator<#0,#1>::type> begin(const boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_base &, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<#0,#1> *, mpl_::bool_<0> *)
boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<#0 *> begin(const boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_base &, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<#0 *,#1> *, mpl_::bool_<1> *)
boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<boost::foreach_detail_::foreach_iterator<#0,#1>::type> begin(const boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_base &, boost::foreach_detail_::type2type<#0,#1> *, mpl_::bool_<1> *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<#0 *> contain(#0 &, mpl_::bool_<0> *)
boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any<#0> contain(const #0 &, mpl_::bool_<1> *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<boost::range_value<#0>::type> is_any_of(const #0 &)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 12 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
#0 & split(#0 &, #1 &, #2, enum boost::algorithm::token_compress_mode_type)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 12 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? * or_(#0 *, #1 *, #2 *)
? * or_(#0 *, #1 *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? * or_(#0 *, #1 *, #2 *)
? * or_(#0 *, #1 *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? * or_(#0 *, #1 *, #2 *)
? * or_(#0 *, #1 *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? * is_array_(const #0 &)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? * is_array_(const #0 &)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? * is_array_(const #0 &)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? * and_(#0 *, #1 *, #2 *)
? * and_(#0 *, #1 *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? * and_(#0 *, #1 *, #2 *)
? * and_(#0 *, #1 *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? * and_(#0 *, #1 *, #2 *)
? * and_(#0 *, #1 *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? * and_(#0 *, #1 *, #2 *)
? * and_(#0 *, #1 *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? * and_(#0 *, #1 *, #2 *)
? * and_(#0 *, #1 *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? * and_(#0 *, #1 *, #2 *)
? * and_(#0 *, #1 *)
'   Prove.cpp   /ProvingGround  line 23 Semantic Error
```

Comment: Thsi problem happens to me as well, for the exact same method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't solved this issue (happens a lot particularly when I use boost it seems), but the root cause may lie in Eclipse' CDT plug-in according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888660/can-not-compile-boostsignal-tutorial-using-gcc-4-5-on-ubuntu-11-04). Brutal workaround is, as discussed in the page, to turn off code analysis feature.