# C++ template function with std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates

I have the following function:

```
template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
void minSortLoop(array<T, SIZE>& a){
    for(size_t o = 0; o < SIZE; o++) {
        size_t minIx = 0;
        for(size_t i = o + 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
            if(a[i] < a[minIx]) {
                minIx = i;
            }
        }
        swap(a[o], a[minIx]);
    }
}
```

I like to call it from the other location like:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr = {3,1,-9};
minSortLoop(arr);
```

But I get the errors:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Invalid arguments ' Candidates
>   are: void minSortLoop(? &) '  Test.cpp    /gTest  line 23 Semantic Error
>
> Description Resource    Path    Location    Type no matching function for call
>   to 'minSortLoop(std::array*)'    Test.cpp    /gTest  line 23 C/C++
>   Problem

How do I call my sort function correctly ?

best regards :-)

PS: I'm not allowed to use std::sort.

---

EDIT 1:

@François Moisan:

I've tried to pass in other ways like:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr = {3,1,-9};
minSortLoop(&arr);
```

with error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Invalid arguments ' Candidates
>   are: void minSortLoop(? &) '  Test.cpp    /gTest  line 23 Semantic Error
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type no matching function for call
>   to 'minSortLoop(std::array*)'    Test.cpp    /gTest  line 23 C/C++
>   Problem

and:

```
std::array<int, 3> arr = {3,1,-9};
minSortLoop(*arr);
```

with error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Invalid arguments ' Candidates
>   are: void minSortLoop(? &) '  Test.cpp    /gTest  line 23 Semantic Error
>
> Description Resource    Path    Location    Type no match for 'operator*'
>   (operand type is 'std::array')   Test.cpp    /gTest  line 23 C/C++
>   Problem

Not sure how to call this. The reference suggests something like my first example [here](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

@tadman:

I need to pass the size. That's given from the task description :-(

@Jarod42: Which compiler is this ? I'm using Cygwin in eclipse under windows 7.

@pasasap: Yes, I compiled it or at least I try. It results in the described errors.

---

EDIT 2:

As @pasasap mentioned in one of the comments, it seems like the problem is because of eclipse. Does anyone know a solution without turning off cody-analysis ?

Comment: Your error suggests the array should be passed by pointer, yet your code seems to take a reference.

Comment: Why would your sort function care about `SIZE`? If it wanted to know it'd ask: `a.size()`. Even if you're not allowed to use `std::sort` you should write something that operates the same way, uses the same interface. Implementing it like this is asking for trouble.

Comment: Compile as expected [here](https://ideone.com/0S4ZcJ) (Even if it doesn't give expected output).

Comment: Can't duplicate. http://ideone.com/unr378.

Comment: Do you use eclipse? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342307/eclipse-returns-error-for-the-code-for-which-g-doesnt Did you try to compile it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: i've edited my answer, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @pasasap: I can confirm that the problem seems to be eclipse. Any ideas how to solve this without turning off code-analysis ?

Comment: Are you using `#include <array>` and are you using a using directive like `using namespace std;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver plz see the comment of pasasap (as i wrote before).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your program, syntactically speaking. The error message suggest errors on your test program. Are you using gTest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is my IDE Eclipse. Once I turned off the code analysis feature it compiled as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It should simply be

```
std::array<int, 3> arr = {3,1,-9};
minSortLoop(arr); // not *arr or &arr
```

Comment: That exactly what I tried in my first example (see above). As @pasasap mentioned, the problem seems to be eclipse. Any ideas how to solve this code-analysis error ? I've been searching but I didn't found any suitable answer yet.

Comment: Have you enabled c++11 or c++14 ?

Comment: I tried to enable c++11 but i already disabled it again because it causes errors too.

Comment: You should use at least c++11 (for `std::array`).

Comment: i currently use -std=gnu++0x which should IIRC be something like c++11.