# Using CCNumber in Cocos2dx applications

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have using the CCNumber repo found [here](https://github.com/MarkusPfundstein/Cocos2DX-Extensions/tree/master/CCNumber) in my Cocos2D-X application. The code

```
 inline int compare(const CCNumber<_typeT>* rhs)
 {
            return memcmp((void*)&m_type, (void*)&rhs->m_type, sizeof(_typeT));
 }
```

gives me an error

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
int memcmp(const void *, const void *, ?)
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: How are you calling compare?

Comment: The error is in the code above, on the return statement ? There is no error on the function call.

Comment: You are using Eclipse. Right?

Comment: yes. I assume this is a Eclipse problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

1. Clean
2. Refresh
3. Rebuild project indexes

**Edit:**
If this doesn't fix the problem. Try disabling Code Analysis as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6934793/408569)

Comment: No does not work. How do you rebuild project indexes ?

Comment: Right-click on the project then Index -> Rebuild

Comment: No such option is available ?

Comment: If you are using Mac OS: Goto Eclipse Preferences -> **C/C++** -> **Indexer** -> Deselect **Enable Indexer** -> **Apply** -> Reenable **Enable Indexer** -> **Apply**